# sed equivalent code for AIX

Tags: sed, aix

Could somebody give me equivalent code for below sed code? it works fine on Linux However I am getting error "sed: 0602-403 /Policy Name:/! d is not a recognized function" when running on AIX.

```
sed -n '
/Policy Name:/! d
    s/.*:\s\+//
    h
    :1
    n
    /Active:\s*no/d
    /HW\//!b1
    :2
    s/.*\s\(\S*\)\s*/\1/
    G
    s/\n/\t/p
    n
    /^\s*$\|Include:/! b2
    '
```

Input file

```
Policy Name:       Today

  Policy Type:       Standard
  Active:              yes
  Effective date:      01/24/2014 11:17:05
  Client Encrypt:      no
  LC/CY/Custmr:  EU         NY  Cindy
                 BU         CA  Victor
                 GU         MI  Bob
  Include:
Policy Name:       Tomorrow

  Policy Type:       Oracle
  Active:              yes
  Effective date:      01/26/2014 11:17:05
  Client Encrypt:      no
  LC/CY/Custmr:  MU         LA  Martha
                 EU         CA  Sam
  Include:
Policy Name:       Yesterday

  Policy Type:       Oracle
  Active:              no
  Effective date:      01/21/2014 11:17:05
  Client Encrypt:      no
  LC/CY/Custmr:  NV         IL  Joe

  Include:
```

Desired Output

```
Cindy    Today     Standard
Victor   Today     Standard
Bob      Today     Standard
Martha   Tomorrow  Oracle
Sam      Tomorrow  Oracle
```

Comment: without testing, I can only suppose that AIX is not expecting a blank after `!` and before `d`, as per the [sed POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html): "It is unspecified whether <blank> characters can follow the '!' character, and conforming applications shall not follow the '!' character with <blank> characters."

Comment: @Sid What bad has `Joe` done to not find his name in the output...is he a policy defaulter? Pls. specify on what basis are you wanting to transform the given input ---> required output.

Comment: @RakeshSharma, So here is the logic, Now I need all the "LC" names adjacent to it their policy names if the policy is active(for Joe the policy "Active" row says no, that's why Joe doesn't suffice) Now in addition to existing code I need Policy Type as well adjacent to it. Makes sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the reworked code to incorporate the policy names, as also to make it POSIX compliant. Notice that all references to `\s` -> `[[:space:]]`, `\S` -> `[^[:space:]]`, `\+` -> `\{1,\}`

P.S.: Not sure what the `/HW\//!b1` line is doing in the orig. code, sitting there like an `appendix`, which can only prove painful if one is not careful.

```
TAB=`printf '\t'`; # literal TAB char will be used below
sed -ne '
   /^Policy Name:/!d

   s/.*:[[:space:]]\{1,\}//;h

   :1
      n
      /Active:[[:space:]]\{1,\}no/d
      /^[[:space:]]*Policy Type:/{
         s/.*:[[:space:]]\{1,\}//;H
      }
   \|^[[:space:]]*LC/CY/Custmr:|!b1

   :2
      s/.*[[:space:]]\([^[:space:]]*\)[[:space:]]*/\1/
      G;s/\n/'"${TAB}"'/pg;n
      /^[[:space:]]*$/d
      /Include:/d
   b2
' yourpolicyfile
```

---

### Results

```
Cindy   Today   Standard
Victor  Today   Standard
Bob     Today   Standard
Martha  Tomorrow        Oracle
Sam     Tomorrow        Oracle
```

Answer (score 2):

```
# define constants
SPC=`echo x | tr x '\040'`
TAB=`echo x | tr x '\011'`
 NL=

# custom regex for...
s="[$SPC$TAB]";   # horizontal whitespace
S="[^$SPC$TAB]";  # non-whitespace

# POSIX compliant sed code...
sed -ne "
   /Policy Name:/!d

   s/.*:$s\{1,\}//
   h

   :1
      n
      /Active:$s*no/d
   /HW\//!b1

   :2
      s/.*$s\($S*\)$s*/\1/
      G
      s/\n/$TAB/p
      n
      /^$s*\$/d
      /Include:/d
   b2
"  yourfile
```

---

### Comments

- `AIX` `sed` does not understand `\s` `\S` as whitespace or nonwhitespace.
- `POSIX` `sed` does not understand a space before a `sed` command, in your case `/.../! d`.
- Also note that the `\+` is not `POSIX`. The correct expression for that is: `\{1,\}` or `$s$s*` where $s are regex atoms.
- `\t` is also not `POSIX`. Here, the shell variable `$TAB` comes in handy.
- The `\|` for the `OR` operation in `sed` is `non-POSIX`. We have to break it up into parts and rearrange the logic.

---

### Caveat

1. It might be that your `shell` tries to do history expansion around the `!d` character. In that case, use single quotes around this region. For the rest the double quotes are required for the `$s, $S, $TAB` variables to be able to be expanded.
2. The `$S` regex WILL match a `\n` as things shown. But that scenario never occurs in your code since you are changing NL -> TAB.

Comment: `\s` matches more than space and tab. The POSIX equivalent is `[[:space:]]`.

Comment: Technically, `/foo/ d` or `/foo/ !d` are POSIX. that's `/foo/! d`, or `/foo/ ! d` that's not (no space between `!` and the command).

Comment: TAB is only `\011` on ASCII based systems. It's better to avoid hardcoding characters based on their byte value in a  specific encoding. `TAB=$(printf '\t')` or `TAB=$(echo x | tr x '\t')` if you prefer `tr`.

Comment: Thanks for the AIX version, However in case I need to edit it to give me another information, current code gives me

`HW Policy Name`

I want to edit it to also give me 

`HW Policy Name Policy Type`

Comment: @Rakesh Sharma Any update? is it possilble?

Comment: @Sid It would be good if you posted your input and the desired output to minimize the iterations.

Comment: @RakeshSharma thanks for the response, I have added it in my question. Let me know in case you need anything else.